# How to use datepicker in rails without gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tried with gem datepicker, but i have to use datepicker without any gem of datepicker?
i have added datepicker js files like

`bootstrap-datepicker.ja.js`
`bootstrap-datepicker.js`

this file i have loaded in view(erb)

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'locales/bootstrap-datepicker.ja.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap-datepicker.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

but it's not working giving error like
in console:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap-datepicker.js):
```

error on page:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in MUser#index
bootstrap-datepicker.js
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form.date_field :date, attribute: 'date' %>
```

where the `:date` is your model

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have jquery included, otherwise you cannot use bootstrap.

try adding `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` in your view above the other two scripts.

So your code should look something like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'locales/bootstrap-datepicker.ja.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap-datepicker.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: this one also not working giving same error.

Comment: Have you tried installing `gem 'jquery-rails'`

Comment: yes, tried with `gem 'jquery-rails'` same error is coming

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at `<%= form.date_field :date_attribute %>` - it will use a native date picker, supported by all major browsers.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date